# Can I implement "sign in with apple" with webview instead of "AuthenicationServiceson" on iOS?

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

I'm currently implementing "sign in with apple" for our apps(both ios and android).

And the server-side already implemented OAuth workflows, so the android side can use webview to auth user and let the server obtain tokens with the auth code.

I’m wondering if I can implement “sign in with apple” with webview instead of AuthenicationServices.framework on iOS like android?

Will this get rejected by the App Store review?

Comment: Does this help? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119198

Comment: @Rob The apple staff in that thread answered the question about putting the button in the webview. I mean, click the native button, open `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?redirect _uri =*&client_id=*`.

Comment: @luoxiu do u get any work around for it

Comment: @AnuragBhakuni The answer is yes, you can use web-based auth flow instead of the native way, and Apple didn't reject our app for that.